# Javascript - Strange string comparison behavior for Urls

Tags: javascript, c#, string

Recently I have encountered a problem of string comparison while writing javascript that I am not able to understand.

I have created two strings from exactly same Url, when I compare them it returns false, but after reassigning the same strings, the comparison returns true.

Here is my example:

```
var str1 = "http://google.com/";
var str2 = "http://google.com‏/";
var eq = str1 == str2;
alert(eq); //print false


str1 = "http://google.com/";
str2 = "http://google.com/";
eq = str1 == str2;
alert(eq); //print true
```

[**Here is the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ca0hv890/)

I have also wrote the same code in C# and results are same, why is this happening, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you copy paste them from somewhere?

Comment: I saw it somewhere but I wrote my own code for this one.

Comment: Try it this way **var eq = (str1 == str2);**

Comment: @Vajura its giving the same result.

Comment: Oh just tested it there is a weird char in one of var str1 = "http://google.com/";
var str2 = "http://google.com‏/"; copy paste one of those to the other and it works

Comment: indeed there was a weird character in between, i think i just copied the string thats why this happened, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an invisible character in your second string between `com` and `/` you can verify that using this foreach loop:

```
foreach(var c in str2)
        Console.WriteLine(c);
```

It prints

```
h
t
t
p
:
/
/
g
o
o
g
l
e
.
c
o
m
‏
/
```

So that's why it returns false.BTW, I just copy/paste your code, when I write it manually it doesn't happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so that was the culprit :) but why that character wasnt visible?